# Sony Smartwatch 3 doesn't ask me to confirm that i have allow ADB Debugging

Tags: android, adb, sony-smartwatch, unauthorized

I follow this guide: https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/debugging.html but when i'm supposed to confirm the debugging on my watch, i have nothing that appears.

Then, my watch appears in UNAUTHORIZED in Android Studio.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things :

1. If you are using Linux, in terminal, run 'sudo adb kill-server' and then 'sudo adb start-server', and see if it works. If this resolves the issue, then you know that there is a problem with the file permissions on you /etc/udev/rules.d/** file, you need to set it to be read as non-sudoer.
2. If you are not using linux, you should still try to 'adb kill-server' and 'adb start-server' on the command line.